# get UID of other users Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm facing an issue regarding `UID`
I've 2 `UIDs` one is customer and other is a driver as shown in the pic below

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMKS9.jpg)

I want to do when customer click then notification send to the driver after he accepted, I get the coordinates
I'm not an expert in firebase
There is the method of `getcurrentuser` but I want to get driver `uid` .
How I get this?
And I searched regarding notifications.
I want to send it programmatically not from console. Mostly tutorials send notifications from the console. I want to send through the button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

   currentFirebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mo = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("My Current Location");
    set_long_lat = new LongtitudeLatitude();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.FDATABASE);
    go=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);



    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !isPermissionGranted()) {
        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    } else requestLocation();
    if (!isLocationEnabled())
        showAlert(1);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    marker =  mMap.addMarker(mo);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude=location.getLatitude();
    longitude=location.getLongitude();

    LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    marker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myCoordinates));
    if (latitude!=null&&longitude!=null)
    {
        set_long_lat.setLat(latitude);
        set_long_lat.setLng(longitude);
        databaseReference.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(set_long_lat);

    }



}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

private void requestLocation() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);
}
private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v("mylog", "Permission is granted");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.v("mylog", "Permission not granted");
        return false;
    }
}
private void showAlert(final int status) {
    String message, title, btnText;
    if (status == 1) {
        message = "Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                "use this app";
        title = "Enable Location";
        btnText = "Location Settings";
    } else {
        message = "Please allow this app to access location!";
        title = "Permission access";
        btnText = "Grant";
    }
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(btnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    if (status == 1) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    } else
                        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}
```

}
Through floating button i want to send notifications programmatically and get the `UID` of driver

Comment: you will have to develop a script that will receive the coordinates and send them to the driver as a notification. Read this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-http-server-protocol , store user UID / details in a DB

Comment: @Manny265 will you send tutorials for this?

Comment: that link I have included will help you send notifications programmatically. as for the users and UIDs I'd suggest you store them in a DB and are able to tell which one is driver and client. where is your code?

Comment: @Manny265 got some idea. Did you help me out for structure. means  i store uid in customer DB and as well as driver uid in driver DB. when customer click. Driver accepts. How customer knows the driver UID. little confusing, how driver knows customer UID. Can you explain more?

Comment: @Manny265 Code added

Comment: The `getCurrentUser.getUid` only returns the uid of the user that is currently logged in. It's unclear on how your app works, but I believe there should be a way to get the specific data you need. With that said, your post is a bit broad. Try to separate the issues with getting the location details and push notification and solve them one by one. IMHO, it'd be easier that way.

Answer (score -1):

Am afraid that this is not possible because Firebase security policies doesn't allow you to retrieve other users unless you store them in your database to use them.

Comment: Don't say this ! :( It's do or die project for me!

Comment: I would recommend you to save the UID of the driver and rider in the Firebase DB so that you need not query for the UID directly. Moreover this is the most secure way.